# Creating relationships with ORM Objects before inserting into a Database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Right now I have double the classes for the same data. The first are the `Bill` and the `Expense` class, used locally to exchange data within the program. I then I have `Bill_Table` and `Expense_Table`, used to exchange data between the program and database. This makes my program needlessly complicated, when I just want one of each.

Bill has a member variable that is a list of Expenses, like so:

```
class Bill:
    vendor = None  # type: str
    expenses = None  # type: list[Expense]
    # plenty more variables here

    def __init__(self, vendor=None,):
        self.vendor = vendor
        self.expenses = list()

class Expense:
    account = None  # type: str
    amount = None  # type: int
    # etc...
```

My `Bill_Table` and `Expense_Table` are set up pretty much identical. I use some functions to convert a `Bill` into a `Bill_table`, or `Expense` into an `Expense_Table`, or visa versa.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Bill_Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bills'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    expenses = relationship("Expense_Table")
    # etc...

class Expense_Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'expenses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bill_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('bills.id'))
    # etc...
```

How would I map some `Expense_Table` objects to a `Bill_Table` object, without connecting to a database? So I could have the same functionality, but also when I insert a `Bill_Table` into the database, it will also import it's `Expense_Table` objects with it too?

Comment: Struggling to understand the question, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: The instrumented list representing the relationship acts pretty much like an ordinary list, so you'd simply assign, `append()`, and/or `extend()`. If and when you add the bill object to the session, the related expense objects are added as well. Is that what you're asking about? Like @AlekseiMaide said, it's a bit hard to understand what's this about.

Comment: To clarify, I want to discard the `Bill` and `Expense` classes and just use the `Bill_Table` and `Expense_Table` classes. I will try using the the append and extend methods.

Comment: That worked perfectly, @IljaEverilä